Which X compositors, if any, support zooming?
I'd like to go without a DE (again) and I got back most of my eye-candy using a compositor (picom) but there is one thing I'm missing, zooming on part of the display.
Which X compositors, if any, support zooming?

The Compiz X compositor supports full-desktop and partial zooming with the Ezoom plugin.

TY for pointing me to Compiz as a compositor, because I think of it as a window manager … and this is troubling me a little bit, so that I have asked a follow-up question.
